# Kendo UI AngularJS Pie Chart seriesClick function does not change variables

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz, kendo-chart

In KendoUI AngularJS demo, telerik shows a seriesHover action that I thought was pretty cool.

I needed an onClick action rather than hover over, thankfully it was as simple as changing the tag from `k-series-hover` to `k-series-click`. I got it do show an alert or log a message in console just fine.

But when I tried to change the value of a variable in the same scope, it does not change that variable value.

```
$scope.hello = "hope";
$scope.onSeriesClick = function(e) {
     kendoConsole.log(kendo.format("event :: seriesHover ({0} : {1})", e.category, e.value));
     $scope.hello = e.category;
 };
```

In fact, there is some really weird behavior:

1. Click the pie chart, console log gets updated. `$scope.hello` is not changed.
2. Click the button on the same scope, `$scope.hello` gets updated to the last clicked pie slice.

I can't really describe it well, so here is the demo:
http://dojo.telerik.com/UTOnO/3

Is this a scope issue??? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether it's considered a bug, but you can fix it by using `$apply`:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.hello = e.category;
});
```